# Calculating average peak-to-peak amplitude in a fft plot

Tags: fft, python, peak-detection

I have the following code to calculate and plot fft. The data consists of voltage, current etc. sampled at 30 samples/sec.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def calculate_fft(data, sampling_rate):
    N = len(data)
    fft_output = np.fft.rfft(data)     # Perform real fft
    fft_freqs = np.fft.rfftfreq(N, d=1/sampling_rate) # Calculatel frequency bins
    fft_magnitudes = np.abs(fft_output)    # Take only magnitude of spectrum
    fft_magnitudes = fft_magnitudes * 2/ N
    return fft_freqs, fft_magnitudes
    
def process_data(data): #replace bad data with the mean value of all good data
    masked_data = data[(data>1)]
    average_value = masked_data.mean() 
    
    data = np.where((data<1), average_value, data)
    
    return data

def main():
    file_path = r'path\file.csv'
    
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
    
    df['col1_1'] = process_data(df['col1'])
    
    sampling_rate = 30
    data_duration = 128
    total_duration = 10*128
    
    num_windows = total_duration // data_duration
    
    for i in range(num_windows):
        start_idx = i*data_duration*sampling_rate
        end_idx = (i+1)*data_duration*sampling_rate
        window_data = df['col1_1'].iloc[start_idx:end_idx]
        fft_freqs,fft_magnitudes = calculate_fft(window_data, sampling_rate)
        #p2p_amplitude = 2*np.sqrt(4,fft_magnitudes)
        p2p_amplitude = 2*np.sqrt(2)*fft_magnitudes
        plt.figure()
        plt.plot(fft_freqs, p2p_amplitude)
        #plt.plot(fft_freqs, fft_magnitudes)
        plt.xlabel('P2P Amplitude')
        plt.ylabel(f'FFT plot - {i+1} of (num_windows) Window')
        plt.xlim(left=0.1,right=10)
        plt.ylim(bottom=0,top=0.03)
        plt.grid()
        plt.show()
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have the following questions:

1. Since I have bad data, I am replacing all the bad data with the mean value of all the good data. Does it corrupt any oscillation that may be present in the data? If yes, what would be a better approach to deal with bad data?
2. My goal is to plot fft that shows average peak to peak amplitude vs frequency. Since I am calculating the fft on a rms value, my understanding is that the fft is giving me rms value of the amplitude at each frequency. Therefore, I just need to multiply the fft magnitude by $2*sqrt(2)$ to get the peak-to-peak value at each frequency bin and plot it. However, in the below tutorial (page 2), the peak-to-peak amplitude calculation can be derived as $2*sqrt(4*fft$_$magtinudes)$. I am not clear which is the correct way of calculating peak-to-peak amplitude of an oscillation present in the data.

Link: https://www.sjsu.edu/people/burford.furman/docs/me120/FFT_tutorial_NI.pdf